# What is the best way to layout this ultra-low inductance capacitor with interleaved pins?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, layout, inductance, decoupling-capacitor

This [TDK capacitor](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/mlcc_commercial_uli_en.pdf) interleaves its pins to reduce inductance.  For a high-pass tee filter, wouldn't I need vias to bring the negative lines off separate from the positive ones?  But vias increase inductance!  Any hints on how to do this in a 1-layer layout?

Here's a pic of the pinout:

[image: MLCC Low Inductance Capacitor]

Comment: You're worried about inductance but you're using a 1 layer layout? that seems a bit weird. What is this for?

Comment: Use multiple vias for each pin.

Comment: It's a waste of money on a one layer board. Your ground return inductance is going to dominate.

Comment: @BeB00, actually its a 4-layer board (or maybe 2-layer with aluminum core, haven't decided), but I want most of the RF on the top layer separated by a ground plane.  These caps are matching components for a 2-stage power amp.

Comment: You only get the super low (hundreds of picohenries) inductance on these when the two power rails (VCC + GND etc.) that the cap is tied to are right on top of each other and as close as possible (think 100μ plane spacing) on layers are right next to the cap. These are not precision matching capacitors, these are power rail decoupling capacitors for chips with edge rates (not clock speed) that have frequency components in the tens to hundreds of GHz. You might find that using an smd cap that's the same width as your microstrips may work quite well, just put a big well via'd 0V fill on one side

Comment: @Sam, do you have an opinion on film/mica/ciramic/tantalum for the hi-pass matching tee?  These caps are in the 10uF range and match between two very unmatched FETs with complex impedances.

Comment: @KJ7LNW it depends a lot on frequency, how small you need it, what power level you are running at and how much loss you can get away with. Film *can* be good for high power but only at low MHz or it'll start to cook from RF heating effects. Mica is very tough and will do RF well, but will be huge for 10uF. Ceramic can be very good but only if you pick the right dielectric, C0G/NP0 are very good for RF but have low capacitance while X5R/X7R are high capacitance but get very lossy at higher frequencies. As for Tants, just... don't, that's a good way to start a fire, tantalums are not RF caps

Comment: @Sam, your comments make great answers to this question. Would you like to copy-paste an answer or shall I?

Comment: @KJ7LNW I'll put something together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10μF sounds like an *awful* lot for a matching capacitor but anyway (unless it's for an RF ground). Now, regarding which type of capacitor to use, as in all things, it depends...

To even make use of the super low (hundreds of picohenries) inductance on those kinds of array capacitors, the two power rails (VCC + GND etc.) that the capacitor is tied to really need to be right on top of each other and as close as possible (think 100μm plane spacing) on layers are right next to the capacitor (so outer most layers).

These are not precision matching capacitors, these are power rail decoupling capacitors for chips with edge rates (not clock speed) that have frequency components in the tens to hundreds of GHz, think CPUs, GPUs and FPGAs

[image: GPU array caps]

There are some important differences between capacitors designed for *de-coupling* RF circuits and capacitors designed for *matching* RF circuits. In some cases you can get away with using decoupling capacitors in a matching circuit but it depends a lot on the frequency you're operating at, how much space you've got for the capacitor, what kinds of power levels you're running at and how much loss you can get away with (very important).

- Film can be good for medium voltage/high power but only at low MHz or it'll start to cook from dielectric losses (put a HDPE cutting board in the microwave, you'll see...)

[image: film cap]

- Mica (specifically silvered mica) is very precise, very stable works well for RF, but will be absolutely enormous for 10uF (pretty sure "500" means 500pF)

[image: silver mica cap]

- Ceramic can be very good for RF but **only** if you pick the right dielectric, C0G/NP0 dielectrics are very good for making low-loss RF capacitors but have low capacitance density while X5R/X7R are high capacitance but get very lossy at higher frequencies

[image: chip caps]

- Tantalum... don't, just... don't. Tantalum has a lot in common with electrolytic (they kinda *are* really) and you wouldn't use an electrolytic capacitor in an RF matching circuit would you? Also, if you overheat them they, well... explode

[image: why we don't use tantalums anymore]

Now something very important that I've not really covered so far is the subject of loss, all capacitors that are not superconducting vacuum capacitors have loss. Now capacitor loss (when available) is often expressed as a unit-less quantity \$tan\delta\$, sometimes just shown as \$\delta\$. When used in the capacitor sense this represents the ratio between the amount of AC power flowing through the capacitor and the amount of power that's being lost as heat within the capacitor. So if my shiny new radio transmitter is pumping out 100W and my antenna DC block capacitor has a \$tan\delta\$ of 0.01 then there's one watt of heat being generated within my capacitor.

Now, things like the silvered mica, teflon and the C0G/NP0 (and vacuum obviously) have very loss loss and can handle a lot of RF power before they give up and decide they want to become light globes. Some film capacitors have reasonable \$tan\delta\$ which is why pretty much all those tesla coil and induction heater kits on the internet all use them for the main resonant tank capacitors, they're not as good as a mica or NP0, but you can actually get them in μF sizes (something that's nearly impossible in the others).

Now the thing you have to remember is that those *other* ceramic dielectrics (that's your X7Rs, your Y5Vs, your JBs etc) those materials have phenomenally high dielectric constants which means huge capacitance in a tiny package ***BUT*** with great dielectric constants comes great dielectric losses (forgive me, I couldn't resist). They're not as bad as tantalums or electrolytics but they're not great when it comes to handling lots of RF energy (they are strongly piezoelectric and so they physically shake at the ripple frequencies). These capacitors are designed for DC power rail applications, so while they have very low inductance, they might also get pretty toasty once you try to pass more than a few tens of watts of RF through them, unless you use one of these unholy beasts... [image: plus ultra capacitor]

There are some ceramic capacitors designed specifically for RF and mmWave applications, these have different internal geometry for the absolute minimum ***parasitic*** series inductance (microstrips have plenty of inductance but it's compensated for) so that when you put one in the middle of a microstrip, the vector network analyser guys would be hard pressed to tell the difference (like these 16kHz - 40GHz ultra-broadband capacitors from American Technical Ceramics)

[image: mmWave cap]

My gut feeling is that if you need 10μF in an RF matching capacitor then something is probably wrong or that you're doing something so specialised (and expensive) that you can probably ring up Knowles or ATC and have them custom make something for you.

***Note***: If you're designing something that runs in the kHz or low MHz region then you can probably use just about anything that isn't electrolytic (but then why worry about an extra nanohenry or two of ESL?)

Comment: Great answer.  It turns out my 10uF match wasn't really matching.  Microwave Office's optimizer went crazy on one of the matching caps and put it at 10uF---which is really just a bypass at that frequency.  I constrained the smulator and its in the 500-1000 pF range.  I think C0G/NP0 is the way to go, mica would be great but its comparatively expensive.  The matching caps will be biased between two PA FETs, so X5R/X7R de-rating is a concern---so I'm definitely sticking to the lower-Er dialectrics in a ceramic.